# How do I make vcredist a launch condition of my MSI installer?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, vcredist

I have a setup project and I want to make [vcredist_x86 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29) & [2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) [launch conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay12wede%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for my application's installer. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: What tools are you using to create the setup?

Comment: An installer should use the merge modules available in c:\program files\common files\merge modules.

Comment: Yes, your installer must use merge modules for VC libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx)